# Running cucumber and capybara in a docker container

Tags: docker, cucumber, capybara, selenium-chromedriver

I have a repo with e2e tests that uses

- Cucumber (ruby) for writing specs and step definitions
- Capybara as a driver to browse and perform user interaction
- Chromedriver

I want a docker container that:

- pulls the repo from `<integration-test-repo-url>`
- installs all the necessary prerequisites (`ruby`, `bundler`, `chromedriver`, `cucumber`)
- goes into the `integration-test-repo` and runs `./runtests.sh` (which installs the prerequisite gems using `bundle install` and then runs `bundle exec cucumber`)

This is what I have so far (using [this](https://hub.docker.com/r/2glab/ruby-chrome-driver/) docker image):

```
FROM 2glab/ruby-chrome-driver

RUN \
  apt-get update && \
  apt-get install -qy bundler && \
  apt-get install -qy cucumber

RUN useradd -d /home/<user> -ms /bin/bash -g root -G sudo -p <user> <password>
USER <user>
WORKDIR /home/<user>

RUN cd && git clone <my_repo_url>
WORKDIR <my_repo_folder>
RUN bundle install && bundle exec cucumber
```

Unfortunately, this results in a error:

`unknown error: Chrome failed to start: crashed
        (Driver info: chromedriver=2.37.544315 (730aa6a5fdba159ac9f4c1e8cbc59bf1b5ce12b7),platform=Linux 4.9.87-linuxkit-aufs x86_64) (Selenium::WebDriver::Error::UnknownError`

How would I fix this? Is chrome missing something? Is Chromedriver missing something? From what I can see, dependencies for chrome and chromedriver should be resolved in the docker image (see [here](https://github.com/2glab/ruby-chrome-driver/blob/master/Dockerfile)).

Comment: Have you configured Capybara to run Chrome in headless mode?  Also note the latest chromedriver is 2.39 - and you may need to configure extra Chrome options in docker depending on your exact setup - see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50610316/capybara-headless-chrome-in-docker-returns-devtoolsactiveport-file-doesnt-exist

Comment: @ThomasWalpole: I was indeed running with the `selenium_chrome_headless` driver (which apparently does not work well in docker. I'll update the question tomorrow and/or link as duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to configure a custom chrome driver instead of using the `selenium_chrome_headless` that ships with chromedriver+capybara:

```
require 'selenium-webdriver'

Capybara.register_driver :custom_chrome_headless do |app|
  browser_options = ::Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome::Options.new
  browser_options.args << '--headless'
  browser_options.args << '--no-sandbox'
  browser_options.args << '--disable-gpu'
  browser_options.args << '--window-size=1920,1080'
  Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(
    app,
    browser: :chrome,
    options: browser_options
  )
end

Capybara.configure do |config|
  config.default_driver = :custom_chrome_headless
  # Other irrelevant config stuff...
end
```

For some reason, this works but `selenium_chrome_headless` does not.

Comment: I'm trying this but still getting Chromium crashing. Is it spec/rails_helper.rb you're putting this in?

Answer (score 0):

I had faced the same issue and fixed it by adding `>options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')>`. Try addding the flag to options.

Comment: Why would writing to `tmp` solve this problem? Afaik that is a fix when chrome starts to use too much memory. Why would this be required simply to start chrome?